# Caching the xml response from a HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, xml, caching, httphandler

My HttpHandler looks like:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";


    XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("ProductFeed");

    DataTable dt = GetStuff();

    for(...)
    {

    }         



    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();


    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();                

}
```

How can I cache the entire xml document that I am generating?

Or do I only have the option of caching the DataTable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. Do not use `XmlTextWriter` unless you're still using .NET 1.1. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.
2. Your use of the `XmlWriter` needs to be in a `using` block, or you'll have resource leaks when an exception is thrown. That's very bad for something like an `HttpHandler`, since it can be called many times.
3. You can create a `MemoryStream` to base your `XmlWriter` on. Create the XML as you currently are, but when you're done, you can "rewind" the `MemoryStream` by setting the `Position` to 0. You can then write the contents of the stream to a file, or wherever you like.

Comment: I want to store it in cache, not file.  Can you help me out with #3?  sounds interesting...

Comment: oh, with XmlWriter I can save to a stringbuilder, and maybe cache that?

Comment: @Blankman: yes, caching the result of a StringBuilder would work.